# Bootbox showing white box behind dialog

Tags: jquery, html, bootbox

I am using bootbox plugin v4.3.0 with metronic and laravel and having this strange issue;

[image]

### JS

```
$('#signup').click(function()
{
    bootbox.alert('some message');
}
```

### Rendered HTML

```
<div style="z-index: 10051;" class="modal-scrollable">
  <div aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; margin-top: -88px;" class="bootbox modal fade bootbox-alert in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button style="margin-top: -10px;" type="button" class="bootbox-close-button close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <div class="bootbox-body">ll</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button data-bb-handler="ok" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with bootstrap bs3 patch CSS file. I have made a solution which essentially reverses the changes made by it for bootbox, it is to be placed in the `bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css` or your master/slave layout if you have any. Also please note, I am a beginner level CSS programmer.

```
.bootbox {
    left: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s !important;
}
```